# AudioKit - Drawing full waveform of file without playground

Tags: ios, swift, waveform, audiokit

Is it possible to draw a complete waveform of file with the AKTable into a UIView? Here is a draft of my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var audioWaveform: WhichClass????

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "drumloop.wav")
    let fileTable = AKTable(file: file)

    audioWaveform.addSubView(????)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just AKTableView:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit/User%20Interface/AKTableView.swift

audioWaveform could be a generic UIView if you just want to add a subview AKTableView to it. Initialize the table view with the frame of the audioWaveform UIView in:

```
AKTableView(fileTable, frame: audioWaveform.frame))
```

Comment: I've complete my script... The App starts but freeze with a blank screen. The Debug Navigator reports CPU load of over 100 %. Where is my mistake?

`@IBOutlet weak var audioWaveform: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let file = try! AKAudioFile(readFileName: "Sounds/drumloop_1.wav")
        let fileTable = AKTable(file: file)
        audioWaveform.addSubview(AKTableView(fileTable, frame: audioWaveform.frame))
  
    }`

Comment: I've checked my code with the debugger. The cpu usage get up to 100 % after the command:

AKTableView.swift
`Linenumber 69: bezierPath.stroke()`

Comment: How big is the file in question? You might have to thin the data down.

Comment: indeed it freezes with high cpu usage. file is 3 seconds .m4a file